# Is it possible to post HTML code using Ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax, jquery

I'm making HTML, PHP and Ajax based site for my university class and having some problems that I can't figure out. Can I post my HTML based Registration Form using Ajax post method to my main PHP site? My code looks like this:

index.php

```
<form id="loginForm" action="login.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br/>
<button id="submit">Login</button>
<button id="regButton">Register</button>
</form>

<div id="ack"></div>
<div id="regAjax"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/scriptAjax.js"></script>
```

register.html

```
<html>
<head><title>Registration Form</title></head>
<body>

<form id="regForm" action="process.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"/><br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"/><br/>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"/><br/>
<button id="register">Register</button>
</form>

<div id="rck"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script/scriptAjax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

scriptAjax.js

```
$("#regButton").click( function() {

$.post ???

$("#regButton").submit( function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

So the main purpose of this to make the smoother page and that registration form would appear in `<div id="regAjax"></div>` place when Register button is clicked, that user could register not being redirected to another page. Is there a way to do that or I'm taking the wrong path now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general Idea is that you have to send the form data to a PHP script that will evaluate it and send a response.

```
$.post( "validate.php", function( data ) {
  $( "#regAjax" ).html( data );
});
```

I recommend you study [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Thank you! The code works perfectly now and that answer is just a sign for me to do more research before I ask. On my way to study the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
method: 'POST',
url: 'validate.php',
data: data,
success: function(result){
 $( "#regAjax" ).html( result );
}
});
```